# How to get host app screen geometry for iOS 8 custom keyboard inside iPhone app running on iPad?

Tags: ios, ios8, uiapplication, custom-keyboard, uiscreen

My Custom keyboard has presets for each screen resolution of all Apple devices. So I have iphone, iphon5, iphone6, iphone6plus and ipad presets.

But in case user runs iPhone app (like instagram) on iPad, I need to load iphone keyboard preset and use its geometry.

Also iPhone 6 and 6+ can use stretched mode, when apps run like iPhone 5 app being stretched.

So determining `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` is not a solution.
Keyboard extension and host app can see screen geometry in different ways, so I am stuck here. Need to get at least application frame for host app or any other explicit way to get that geometry.

**App and keyboard extension see geometry different ways:**
[image: App and keyboard extension see geometry different ways]

Also Swift key seems to have same bug while running hosted inside of iphone app on ipad screen.

**Swiftkey inside iphone app on ipad:**
[image: Swiftkey inside iphone app on ipad]

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way to check isPad on keyboard extension but I cannot make sure it is best way.

UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() && YourKeyboardViewController.instance.view.bounds.size.width == UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width

You should do this after YourKeyboardViewController.instance did called viewWillAppear(), after that the view.bounds did changed to 320x480 from 768x1024.